# Throughput and response time using Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, performancecounter

How can I find out maximum throughput my application can achieve within sla of 1 sec as response time.i.e response time should be within 1 sec

Currently I am using throughput controller and setting up the required throughput per minute, but I need to know max throughput my application can deliver with average response time less then 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Using Thread Group, set Number of Threads (users) to some big number and set rump-up period to e.g.: 600s (10min) 
Jmeter will slowly increase throughput and you can monitor Max response time in Summary report (column Max) - when it starts reaching 1s, you can read your desired Throughput (in Throughput column) Then I recommend set this number to Number of threads, decrease rump-up and run test for couple of hours.

Avoid using sleeps in your loop in JMeter. Beware of cache at application side. Monitor Faults in Error columns and check system health on both sides (CPU,mem,IO,Netw,...)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) does not control the throughput.

Following is from the JMeter official site.

> This controller is badly named, as it does not control throughput.
>   Please refer to the [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) for an element that can
>   be used to adjust the throughput.

You may use plugin [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) if you want to have controlled throughput changing with the time.

Change the threads (virtual users) and throughput to check the maximum through that can be handled by the server.

[Use Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) to check the response time of each desired sampler.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't limit JMeter's throughput.

Start with 1 thread (virtual user) and gradually increase the load until you see response times exceeding 1 second (you can use i.e. [AutoStop Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right/) plugin for automatically stopping the test when average response becomes higher than 1 second)

Once done you can look into [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) and [Server Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/), it will give you the number you're looking for.